# How to call database through Ajax calls NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, cross-domain

I am using a MongoDB database which stores different data about different countries. I have different pie charts displaying different data, but I want to add the ability for the user to choose which year they want to see. I am trying to make AJAX calls to my database when the user selects a specific year, but I get errors when accessing the MongoDB database that is on mlab. What is the best way to go about getting the data? Can it be done completely on the client side or does it have to go through back end?

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxxx.mlab.com...',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
```

This is what I have but does not work, but I am unsure if this approach is even the correct approach. Please let me know the best way for going about this.

Comment: That isn't the correct approach, you must create some `API` and after  you can fetch data from you API with AJAX

Comment: i have a single page that displays different charts, and so i want the ability to fetch data to refresh a single chart but without refreshing the page. Would creating some API allow this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you can make an ajax call to the mongo database. 
The way that I have done it in the past is to make an ajax call to a node get function. That function will then query the database.

Comment: Would the page have to refresh for this to work? If you see my comment above I need the ability to retrieve data without refreshing the page. If I understand correctly then I believe your approach may work to my needs, correct?

Comment: Ajax calls to node and then from node to the database are done /without/ refreshing the page.